# How to share cookie across different domains NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, jwt

I have this return statment in my backend code:

```
return res
.status(200)
.cookie("auth_token", token, {
  httpOnly: false,
  domain: "domain.com",
  secure: true,
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (6 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
})
.send({
  data: token,
  code: "100",
  message: `AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS. IP: ${clientIP}, Geo: ${location}, Info: ${
    (app, os)
  }`,
});
```

which saves a JWT token on domain `domain.com`, I'd like this to also work with `domain2.com`, for example, as my authentication system is now used for multiple sites and it runs off of a different domain to `domain2.com`.

A user goes on site `domain.com` and that site checks if a `auth-token` cookie is present, if not it should redirect to a completely different domain `auth.domain2.com`. This is where the user authenticates; once they have autenticated themselves the above return statment should save the cookie in their browser for ideally `domain.com` and `domain2.com`. After, they are redirected back to `domain.com` for it to then check if the `auth-token` cookie is present once again, if so, check it's valid, and then allow the user in.

I have tried to just save the cookie for the domain thats not the domain the autenticated code is run on (the code above for example): `domain: "domain.com"` to `domain: "domain2.com"` it still will not work/save the cookie for that domain.

Is this possible? If not what are the workarounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies from one domain cannot be accessed from another domain, but this is actually *not* necessary.

The logon flow that you describe implies for me that you need *two* cookies:

1. User visits `domain.com` and a logon flow starts with a redirection to `auth.domain2.com`.
2. User posts their credentials to `auth.domain2.com` and receives a response that

   - sets a cookie A for domain `auth.domain2.com` and
   - redirects the browser back to `domain.com` (with a SAML response or a JWT or an authorization code or something that indicates that the user has successfully logged on).
3. In response to the request `domain.com?SAMLResponse=...`, the browser receives a cookie B (a JWT named `auth_token` in your case) for domain `domain.com`.

After that, every request that the browser makes to `domain.com` contains cookie B, which therefore establishes a session with `domain.com`.

If the user later visits `domain3.com` (or returns to `domain.com` after having logged off), a second logon flow to `auth.domain2.com` is started, but this time, the request to `auth.domain2.com` contains cookie A. Therefore, `auth.domain2.com` immediately redirects the browser back to `domain3.com`, without asking for credentials in step #2 above.

In other words: Cookie A establishes a session with `auth.domain2.com`, and cookie B establishes a session with `domain.com`. (And a third cookie C establishes a session with `domain3.com` in step #3 of the second logon flow.)

This should fulfil your requirements.

Comment: so you are saying I should put the token within the url as a query param on the redirect to the page they want to access?

Comment: Yes. Or you send the browser back with a POST request (auto-submitting HTML form), so the token is part of the urlencoded payload.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was actually looking for a better login flow.

Comment: You can also use authorization code flow, where domain.com exchanges an authorization code from the URL for a JWT with a server-to-server request to auth.domain2.com.